# Resize image downloads for IPFS assets in CloudFlare

Tags: cloudflare, ipfs, nft, cardano

I am writing a Swift iOS app that uses [Blockfrost.io](https://blockfrost.io) to download assets from the Cardano blockchain. The asset's images come in the format `ipfs://QmSJPFVN...`, which can be retrieved by using the URI in a CloudFlare URL, like this `https://cloudflare-ipfs.com/ipfs/QmSJPFVN...`.

My issue is that most of the images I'm trying to fetch and display are enormous, and it's seriously slowing down my UI. Are there parameters that can be added to the URL to specify a smaller image size to be fetched? I've looked around for a solution but haven't been able to find any.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options for this -

1. Use a 'proxy' to fetch the image server-side and convert before downloading. Could make use of a Cloudflare worker for instance - https://developers.cloudflare.com/images/image-resizing/resize-with-workers
2. Download the full size image, but convert it within your app before displaying it in the UI. You'll still use full amount of bandwidth in this approach, but may reduce complexity.